# append distinct count for each line in a file in unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix, line-count

I have a big file with field separator #~# and records like

```
bus#~#337007270#~#461692988#~#2019-09-24 01:06:33#~#103  
bus#~#337007270#~#461692988#~#2019-09-24 01:06:33#~#115
bus#~#337007270#~#461692988#~#2019-09-24 01:06:33#~#117
bus#~#337007270#~#461692988#~#2019-09-24 01:06:33#~#103 -> repeat of 1st
bus#~#337007270#~#461692988#~#2019-09-24 01:06:33#~#118
bus#~#337007270#~#461692988#~#2019-09-24 01:06:33#~#129
bus#~#337007270#~#461692988#~#2019-09-24 01:06:33#~#130
bus#~#337007270#~#461692988#~#2019-09-24 01:06:33#~#132
bus#~#337007270#~#461692988#~#2019-09-24 01:06:33#~#133
```

How can I process this file to record the occurrence count as below

```
bus#~#337007270#~#461692988#~#2019-09-24 01:06:33#~#103#~#2 
bus#~#337007270#~#461692988#~#2019-09-24 01:06:33#~#115#~#1
bus#~#337007270#~#461692988#~#2019-09-24 01:06:33#~#117#~#1
bus#~#337007270#~#461692988#~#2019-09-24 01:06:33#~#118#~#1
bus#~#337007270#~#461692988#~#2019-09-24 01:06:33#~#129#~#1
bus#~#337007270#~#461692988#~#2019-09-24 01:06:33#~#130#~#1
bus#~#337007270#~#461692988#~#2019-09-24 01:06:33#~#132#~#1
bus#~#337007270#~#461692988#~#2019-09-24 01:06:33#~#133#~#1
```

Thank You.

Comment: It looks like the last field is the only one changing? Or do you need to verify all rows are the exact same?

Comment: Looks a job for 'sort' and 'uniq -c'

Comment: You are expected to perform basic research and make an effort. Please show the relevant code and state where you are having problems. Also see [Why is the “how to move the turtle in logo” question closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158289) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below :

```
sort filename |uniq -c|awk '{print $2,$3"#~#"$1}'
```

Output :

```
bus#~#337007270#~#461692988#~#2019-09-24 01:06:33#~#103#~#2
bus#~#337007270#~#461692988#~#2019-09-24 01:06:33#~#115#~#1
bus#~#337007270#~#461692988#~#2019-09-24 01:06:33#~#117#~#1
bus#~#337007270#~#461692988#~#2019-09-24 01:06:33#~#118#~#1
bus#~#337007270#~#461692988#~#2019-09-24 01:06:33#~#129#~#1
bus#~#337007270#~#461692988#~#2019-09-24 01:06:33#~#130#~#1
bus#~#337007270#~#461692988#~#2019-09-24 01:06:33#~#132#~#1
bus#~#337007270#~#461692988#~#2019-09-24 01:06:33#~#133#~#1
```

Comment: awk is also separating the timestamp value 2019-09-24 01:06:33

Comment: @D.Aquar Edited it. Try now.

Comment: @D.Aquar You're welcome. If you feel it helped, please accept it as a valid answer so that it helps others. Thanks.